# Non-Advaitan Smartas

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, smarta

Are their Smartas who are non-Advaitan and hold that Ishvara is represented equally in the forms of Brahma, Vishnu, Shiva, Shakti, Ganesha, and Skanda, but isn't Nirguna or without attributes.

Comment: Smārtas uphold Advaita siddhānta only, there are no non-Advaitin smārtas. Īśvara is not Nirguṇa Brahman, however both share the same cetana svabhāva/svarūpa. Brahmā, Viṣṇu, etc. are all svarūpas of Saguṇa Brahman. And only Nirguṇa Brahman is the pāramārthika satya.